# image is not showing in emulator react native

Tags: image, react-native

i have list in which i want to show image like this

[image]

this is my list component I have giving correct path but nothin happens  have giving width and height but no luck

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
} from "react-native";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import AppText from "./AppText";

export default function ListItem({ image, title, sutitle }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
      <View style={styles.tittleContainer}>
        <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
        <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{sutitle}</AppText>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        borderRadius: 35,
        marginRight: 10,
      },
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  sutitle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: colors.red,
  },
 
  tittleContainer: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
});
```

I am unable to render image on my screen

[image]

Comment: Whats the value passed to image in source={image}?

Comment: In the 2nd screenshot, I am able to see Anna Bella image, if that is what you are expecting. What is the problem you are facing? If it the image not respecting style settings?

Comment: actually i have put a dummy image in anabella

Comment: <ListItem
            Image={require("../assets/dummyFemale.png")}
            title="Anna bella"
            sutitle="suck 5 person blood"
          />

Comment: are you sure the image path you havae entered is correct

Comment: check above image path is working and below dont

Comment: <View>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Image
          style={styles.CardImage}
          source={require("../assets/child.png")}
        />

        <View style={styles.tittleContainer}>
          <AppText style={styles.title}>Need your blood</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>$300</AppText>

          <ListItem
            Image={require("../assets/child.png")}
            title="Anna bella"
            sutitle="suck 5 person blood"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is while providing props to ListItem component you're passing "Image". and while using it in the component you're using "image".
I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Image is working copy past your code nothing else,
check your image path correctly
https://snack.expo.io/@jsfit/image

export default function ListItem({ image, title, sutitle }) { in this params you are getting the image as lower `i` and when you are passing with Image as capital `I`.

Comment: i am not understanding

Comment: what was my mistake

Comment: which image are you using local or HTTP?

Comment: i am using local image

Comment: because there is no mistake in your provided code, do one more thing just comment your ```AppText``` component

Comment: check is HTTP image is loading or not?

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: ```export default function ListItem({ image, title, sutitle }) {``` in this you are getting the image as lower `i` and when you are passing then ....?

Comment: @kokab well,  hope you will not make that mistake next time

Comment: i will try @ilyas